# Python Big Query - Ability to check if authorized views exisit from source dataset and how to remove it

Tags: google-bigquery

I am writing a python script that creates/updates views in the dataset from an SQL script.

I am wondering if it is possible for me to check if an authorized view has been created in the dataset. If so and I wish to delete it, is there a python method that does so?

Comment: Hi Rootie! Could you please upvote/accept the answer? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For authorized views we need to create a separate dataset and give access to it. Next step is to create view in that dataset and everyone who has access to dataset gets access to the view.

I can see following possibilities to remove authorized view:

1. Remove `AccessEntry` from dataset.
2. Remove view from dataset.
3. Remove the whole dataset with all views and access given to it.

Let's take a look for [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views), where you can find Python example. We need to perform two operations. Firstly unauthorize the view to remove access to the source dataset, then remove access controls to the dataset containing the view. We need to use `remove()` method:

```
# Unauthorize the view to access the source dataset
access_entries = source_dataset.access_entries
access_entries.remove(
    bigquery.AccessEntry(None, 'view', view.reference.to_api_repr())
)
source_dataset.access_entries = access_entries
source_dataset = client.update_dataset(
    source_dataset, ['access_entries']) 

# Remove access controls to the dataset containing the view
analyst_group_email = 'data_analysts@example.com'
access_entries = shared_dataset.access_entries
access_entries.remove(
    bigquery.AccessEntry('READER', 'groupByEmail', analyst_group_email)
)
shared_dataset.access_entries = access_entries
shared_dataset = client.update_dataset(
    shared_dataset, ['access_entries'])
```

Additionally, here you can find multiline for-loop example, which removes the access:

```
source_dataset = bigquery_client.get_dataset(dataset_id)
access_entries = source_dataset.access_entries

for access_entry_data in access_entries:
    dict_auth = access_entry_data.entity_id
    if isinstance(dict_auth, dict):
        if dict_auth['tableId'] == resource:
            idx = access_entries.index(access_entry_data)
            access_entries.pop(access_entries.index(access_entry_data))
            source_dataset.access_entries = access_entries
            source_dataset = bigquery_client.update_dataset(source_dataset, ['access_entries'])
```

To read more about `AccessEntry`, please visit [official documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.AccessEntry.html).